# Change div background colors according to array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have divs that are loaded from a database, the number of divs is not known ( may increase or decrease ) , each div have a random color from my code :

```
$(".ooicon").each(function() {
  var items = ["#9062aa","#3fb4e9","#6fc063","#d94949","#f8951e","#7a564a","#029688","#2d2f79","#e81f63"];
  var color = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
  $(this).css('background', color);
});
```

this code gives a random color changed on each reload or refresh , I want to make  the colors static and not changed on refresh,

for example the first div will have the color `#9062aa` from the code, the second will be `#3fb4e9` and so on.. when the colors in the array reach the last, it start over again with the first color.

I hope you understand me.

Comment: `var color = items[index % items.length];` `index` is passed as an argument to the callback function of `each`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DO not keep your colors array in .each loop, dont seem to be good 
code. so if you divide current index of item in .each loop with length,
you will get desired reset logic to chose color from array.

```
 var items = ["#9062aa","#3fb4e9","#6fc063","#d94949","#f8951e",
 "#7a564a","#029688","#2d2f79","#e81f63"];

 $(".ooicon").each(function(index) {

   var color = items[index % items.length];
   $(this).css('background', color);

  });
```

This should work,hope this helps.

Comment: What's the point of adding the exact same answer as already provided?

Comment: He he , good question , check the timestap please , mine is earlier though.

Comment: No it's not. My answer is 4 minutes before yours.

Comment: Correctly observed , now the point is I was typing my answer you might have typed and posted the exact same answer, so that has happened, please try to understand that too :(

Answer (score 1):

You just have to loop over the array without using random, and when the index is equal to the array items, reset it to 0.

See below snippet:

```js
var items = ["#9062aa", "#3fb4e9", "#6fc063", "#d94949", "#f8951e", "#7a564a", "#029688", "#2d2f79", "#e81f63"];
var index = 0;
var color;
$(".ooicon").each(function() {
  if (index == items.length)
    index = 0;

  color = items[index];
  $(this).css('background', color);
  index++;
});
```

```css
.ooicon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="ooicon"></div>
<div class="ooicon"></div>
<div class="ooicon"></div>
<div class="ooicon"></div>
<div class="ooicon"></div>
<div class="ooicon"></div>
<div class="ooicon"></div>
<div class="ooicon"></div>
<div class="ooicon"></div>

<div class="ooicon"></div>
<div class="ooicon"></div>
<div class="ooicon"></div>
<div class="ooicon"></div>
<div class="ooicon"></div>
<div class="ooicon"></div>
<div class="ooicon"></div>
<div class="ooicon"></div>
<div class="ooicon"></div>
<div class="ooicon"></div>
<div class="ooicon"></div>
<div class="ooicon"></div>
```

Comment: You don't need to maintain an `index` here at all, as one is passed to `each()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , yep you're right , missed that , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The colours change as you're using `Math.random()`. If you want them colours to be static based on the position of the elements in the set, use their index value instead. This can be retrieved as the first argument provided to `each()`:

```
var items = ["#9062aa", "#3fb4e9", "#6fc063", "#d94949", "#f8951e", "#7a564a", "#029688", "#2d2f79", "#e81f63"];

$(".ooicon").each(function(i) {
  var color = items[i % items.length)];
  $(this).css('background-color', color);
});
```

Note that I moved the `items` declaration *outside* of the loop; there's no point redefining the same data in each iteration. Also note the use of the modulo operator (`%`) to simplify the iterative access of the  array, and the change to set `background-color` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without using math.random, check below snippet :

```js
var colors = ["#9062aa","#3fb4e9","#6fc063","#d94949","#f8951e","#7a564a","#029688","#2d2f79","#e81f63"];
var count = 0;

function bgcolor() {
  $("body").find("div").each(function() {
    var index = $("body").find("div").index(this);
    var i = (index + count) % colors.length;
    $(this).css("background-color", colors[i]);
  });
  count++;
}

$(window).resize(bgcolor);
$(document).ready(bgcolor);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Content -1</div>
<div>Content - 2</div>
<div>Content - 3</div>
<div>Content - 4</div>
<div>Content - 5</div>
<div>Content - 6</div>
<div>Content - 7</div>
<div>Content - 8</div>
<div>Content - 9</div>
<div>Content - 10</div>
<div>Content - 11</div>
<div>Content - 12</div>
<div>Content - 13</div>
```